# Group representation preserving finitely many generators

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $\rho : G \rightarrow GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ be a representation of $G$.

If $G$ is finitely generated as a group, does that mean that $im(\rho) \leq GL_n(\mathbb{C}) $ is finitely generated? Because, if $g$ is a generator for $G$, this does not necessarily imply that $\rho(g)$ is a generator for $im(\rho)$ does it?

For example, does $G = \langle x_1, ..., x_n \rangle$ imply that $im(\rho) = \langle \rho(x_1), ... , \rho(x_n) \rangle $?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to talk about some $g\in G$ being a generator, rather than an element of a generating set. If $S$ is a generating set of $G$, then clearly $f(S)$ is a generating set of $f(G)$ for any homomorphism $f$.

Comment: @anomaly So, say $G = \langle a,b \rangle$, does this mean that $im(\rho) = \langle \rho(a), \rho(b) \rangle$?

Comment: Sure: If $g = x_1 \cdots x_n$, then $f(g) = f(x_1) \cdots f(x_n)$.

Comment: A homomorphic image of a finitely generated group is always finitely generated. Doesn't mater what the target space is. As to your final question: yes; think about it. Every element in $\rho(G)$ is $\rho(g)$ for some $g\in G$, and such a $g$ can be written in terms of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, and since $\rho$ is a homomorphism....

Comment: Avoid saying "does it meant that" when you mean "does it imply that". Also, "generator" is senseless. A "generator" is a convenient way to refer to an element of a given generating subset. But it has no meaning in general (without reference to a fixed known generating subset).

Answer (score 0):

> **Lemma.** If $f:G\to H$ is a group homomorphism and $G=\langle S\rangle$ for some subset $S\subseteq G$ then $f(G)=\langle f(S)\rangle$.

*Proof.* "$\supseteq$" since $f(S)\subseteq f(G)$ then by definition of the generated subgroup we get $\langle f(S)\rangle\subseteq f(G)$.

"$\subseteq$" Assume that $H'$ is a subgroup of $H$ such that $f(S)\subseteq H'$. It follows that $S\subseteq f^{-1}(H')$ and since $f^{-1}(H')$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $G=\langle S\rangle$ then $f^{-1}(H')=G$. Therefore $f(G)= ff^{-1}(H')\subseteq H'$. So we've proved that every subgroup containing $f(S)$ has to contain $f(G)$. In other words $f(G)\subseteq \langle f(S)\rangle$. $\Box$

Note that this is pure group theory. No notion of matrices, complex numbers or representations is need.

**Corollary.** If $G$ is finitely generated then so is $f(G)$.

*Proof.* Simply because an image of a finite set via any function is finite. Apply previous lemma. $\Box$

Note however that the image of an infinitely generated group need not be infinitely generated as trivial homomorphism shows.

> For example, does $G = \langle x_1, ..., x_n \rangle$ imply that $im(\rho) = \langle \rho(x_1), ... , \rho(x_n) \rangle $?

Yes, although note that $\rho$ need not be injective. I.e. it may happen that $G=\langle x, y\rangle$ and $im(\rho)=\langle\rho(x)\rangle$ if $\rho(x)=\rho(y)$.